# How to loop through specific range to find highlighted yellow cells?

Tags: excel, vba, loops, if-statement

I'm trying to create a code that loops through a specific range and finds the cells that are highlighted yellow. When identified, I need to check if the cell range in the same row as the yellow highlighted cell(s) is highlighted green.

Comment: Look into `for` loop and `colorindex`.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
For i = 2 To 2975
    For c = 19 To 21
        If Cells(i, c).Interior.ColorIndex = 6 Then
            If Cells(i, c - 6).Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then
                Cells(i, c - 6).Formula = "=ROUNDUP(((L2*83.6)/20900) - SUM(N2:O2),2)"
            End If
        End If
    Next
Next
```